# How to align UITableView frames one after one and fit into UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have multiple `UITableView` in a `UIScrollView`. The size of the tables depends on the number of rows it has. The tables are arranged in a sequence of one below another.

```
Table 1
Table 2
Table 3
```

Now let's say Table 1 ends at the position of '**x**', I want the table 2 move to the position '**x**' and the same for table 3 to move where table 2 ends at. And at the end, the UIScrollView fit all the tables.
I am new to iOS that's why not sure how to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use multiple stacked table views? I think it will be easier if you use one table view and separate it so each of your old table views in a section in the single table view.

Comment: @AdamPro13 One table for invoices, One table debits, One table for credits. Can I fit them in one table and separate them like you said?

Comment: Yep, you can fit them into a single table view with 3 sections! I'm pretty sure that is what you actually want. You will likely want to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` method `- tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` or if you want a more custom header to each section implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `-tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`.

Comment: @AdamPro13 how to do that? Sorry I'm new

Comment: There are many tutorials about `UITableView` available on the Internet. You need to work through some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to create custom class of `UITableView` and disable it's scroll view.

```
@implementation SizedTableView

- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize {
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
   [self layoutIfNeeded]; 
   return CGSizeMake(UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, self.contentSize.height);
}

@end
```

Create a custom class with Subclass of `UITableView` and add above two methods.

Add all tableview to scrollview and add proper constraint to work.

[image]

To avoid storyboard constraint error you have to add tableview placeholder height constraint which will remove at build time. You can add it from attributed inspector.

Comment: Okay let me try this out

Comment: in case, if I don't want to use constraints, then how can I do? because the project I'm working on, that one was developed by someone else and he never used constraints in his desing

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar For that you have to calculate all tableview content size and according to that you have to set your scrollview content size. update tableview frame accordingly.

Comment: can I simply do that by getting table height? If so, I have tried that but the table positioning is not changing

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar when you are getting your table height?

Comment: after `[self.table reloadData]`

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar you have to get height of table's contentSize.

Comment: `CGFloat height = self.Table.rowHeight;
    height *=  Array.count;`  this is how i'm getting @iDhaval

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar This is how you should get height of table `table.contentSize.height`

Comment: thanks got the exact height. How can I position another table at that position?

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151328/discussion-between-idhaval-and-mohammad-julfikar).

Answer (score 1):

Set `int tableHeight = numberOfRows * RowHeight;`

and set table frames as

```
table1.frame = [CGRectMake(0, 0,scrollView.frame.size.width , tableHeight)];
table2.frame = [CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(table1.frame),scrollView.frame.size.width , tableHeight)];
table3.frame = [CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(table2.frame),scrollView.frame.size.width , tableHeight)];
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: This answer doesn't take rotation or resizing into account. If you're new to iOS, I highly recommend avoiding this way.

Comment: Sure... Thanks!!

Comment: @AdamPro13 how can we implement then? I think we can add constraints to meet autoresizing needs.

Comment: Your approach would work if the table view's content is static and you set each table view's `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, which should cause the table view to stretch when its superview changes its size. If the content in each table view is dynamic, you'd need to be notified after the tableView reloaded its data so you could recalculate the height each time.

Answer (score 0):

Use one `NSMutableArray` and separate the data for each `UITable` by setting individual key for them. using multiple tables in one view controller is not a good idea